# How to properly return values from unmanaged interface method?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, xulrunner, geckofx

I'm in the process of extending GeckoFx (http://geckofx.org) and am having some problems returning array values from unmanaged interfaces provided by XPCom.

I've added a great amount of new feature support to GeckoFx using the latest XulRunner 1.9.2.13 build but, I'm getting access violation exceptions when attempting to return arrays from interface methods.
Eg:

```
[Guid("43987F7B-0FAA-4019-811E-42BECAC73FC5"), ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface mozISpellCheckingEngine
{
    //...
    void GetDictionaryList([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]ref string[] dictionaries, out uint count);
    //...
}

public static string[] GetAvailableDictionaries()
{
    string[] _dictionaries = null;
    uint count = 0;

    //GetSpellChecker() returns a valid mozISpellCheckingEngine object
    GetSpellChecker().GetDictionaryList(ref _dictionaries, out count);
    if (count > 0)
    {
        if (_dictionaries != null)
        {
            return _dictionaries;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The problem is when GetDictionaryList returns sometimes it will return a list with a single index and containing the name of one dictionary (I have 2 dictionaries in the location this method searches in) and count returns with the correct value of 2; other times the method will fail and throw an access violation and the value of _dictionaries is string[0] while count remains correct with the value of 2.

I guess the biggest part of this question would have to be 'Am I marshaling the method and its parameters correctly in the interface declaration?'.

This example code is just that - an example. There are several other XulRunner features I would like to implement in GeckoFx but, they return arrays as well and suffer from the same problem. Until I can get past this issue my work is at a bit of a stand-still.

Thanks for any and all help you can provide.

-Scott

Comment: Try dropping the `ref` keyword from the array argument, since that implies pointer-to-pointer-to-data (arrays are implicitly pointers in C#), and my guess is the interface specifies pointer-to-data (as is common for C arrays).

Comment: did you have access to unmanage code to edit it?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
void GetDictionaryList([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]ref string[] dictionaries, out uint count);
```

to:

```
void GetDictionaryList(ref IntPtr dictionaries, out uint count);
```

and use it like:

```
IntPtr dictionaries = IntPtr.Zero;
int count;

GetDictionaryList(ref dictionaries, count);

 // check dictionaries != IntPtr.Zero; and count > 0

 // dictionaries will be a IntPtr to array IntPtr (of size count)

 string vals = new string[count];

 for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
  vals[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)) * i);
```

(I haven't compiled this code so there may be typos.)

Comment: Actually, I answered the question on my own several minutes after posting it..                                                                The answer provided above is pretty close to what I ended up with.